# Is it appropriate to ask for opinions on individual reviewers?

Tags: discussion, reviews

In photography, much unlike software development, much of the information we have on equipment, technique, etc, is highly subjective.  This means we spend a great deal of time reading review sights, tutorials, and other highly subjective reading material.

Is it appropriate to ask a question like "Can I trust Ken Rockwell's camera lens reviews?"

I obviously do not want the answers to turn into a Rockwell-bashing party (or a Rockwell-worship party, either).  The purpose would be to seek honest opinions about the reliability and accuracy of his reviews.  But the fact that the reviews are tied to an individual makes the issue seem potentially more explosive.

Perhaps it's the same as "Can I trust reviews from photodo.com?"  Would that be appropriate?

Comment: Ol' Kenny boy is not the best example - from his about page "this is a personal website, and never presented as fact. I enjoy making things up for fun, as does The Onion, and I publish them here" http://www.kenrockwell.com/about.htm  . I'm not bashing at all, he says it himself, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: That and we've already asked it...http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/are-websites-like-kenrockwell-com-and-bythom-com-reliable

Comment: Fair enough :)  Pick any other example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems too broad to me.

Rather than

> Can I trust Joe Smith's reviews?

why not focus on specific elements of the review

> Is there any truth to Joe Smith's claims that Enormo-Lens 5000 has significant optical distortion at the edges of the frame?

or at the very least roll up several specific questions about one product being reviewed.

The other angle here to "teach people to fish", so to speak, is to ask a general question about how to verify accuracy of a review of a particular product -- *any* review by *any* camera buff.

Comment: That might be fine from a purely technical stand point, but I might be interested in knowing if Joe Smith's reviews are slanted toward landscape photography, but tend to ignore portrait photography, for instance. That's not always obvious from reading a single review... And it could make his reviews priceless for a landscape photographer, while close to worthless for others.

Comment: the answer to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/are-websites-like-kenrockwell-com-and-bythom-com-reliable is pretty much a 'teach a man to fish answer' and covers it